# Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.TryUnsnap() is obsolete

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps

```
bool isSnapped;
    async void EnsureUnsnapped()
    {
        // FilePicker APIs will not work if the application is in 
        //a snapped state
        // If an app wants to show a FilePicker while snapped, it
        //must attempt to unsnap first
        bool unsnapped = ((Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value != Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.Snapped) || Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.TryUnsnap());
        if (!unsnapped)
        {
            MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Cannot open file picker in snapped view. ");
            await msg.ShowAsync();
            isSnapped = true;

        }
        else
        {
            isSnapped = false;
        }
    }
    string GetNotes()
    {
        string response = "";
        foreach (var note in NotesCollection.Notes)
        {
            response += "Title ->  " + note.Title + Environment.NewLine + "Content -> " + note.Content + Environment.NewLine + "*****************************" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return response;
    }
    private async void bttnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EnsureUnsnapped();
        if (!isSnapped)
        {
            if (NotesCollection.Notes.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder documentFolder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;

                    var file = await documentFolder.CreateFileAsync("Notes.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, GetNotes());
                        MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Notes are saved in the Documents Library in a file named Notes.txt");
                        await msg.ShowAsync();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("No notes exists to save.");
                await msg.ShowAsync();
            }

        }

    }
```

The codes have been re-targeted to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8. While executing the Windows store app I'm getting these warning:

'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.TryUnsnap()' is obsolete: 'TryUnsnap may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Apps can be continuously resized, but cannot be snapped, starting in Windows 8.1.'

'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value' is obsolete: 'Value may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, query for window layout sizes directly.'

'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState' is obsolete: 'ApplicationViewState may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, query for window layout sizes directly.'

How to solve this warning message? As the bttnSave_Click() method is also not working.

Comment: From the error itself and from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263110.aspx 
 check section **Window size model** under **Change descriptions** there is no snapped view in windows8.1

Answer (score 2):

You solve the warnings by not using those APIs. Windows 8.1 improves upon the Windows 8 view model by allowing variable sizing rather than the fixed snapped/filled/fullscreen views. The key here is that you set a minimum width in your manifest. By default, that width is 500px rather than the 320px snap view. If you want to support the narrow (former "snap") view, then you can specify a minimum width of 320px in the manifest, But otherwise, Windows 8.1 won't allow the app to be sized smaller.

In your scenario, the reason you're checking for snap view and trying to unsnap is to allow the file picker to work. If you keep the 500px min width in the manifest for Windows 8.1, then you don't need any of these checks at all because the file picker will work at 500px.

If you support going below 500px, then you need to do a similar check, but instead of checking the old ApplicationViewState value you just check the view's width directly. Then you can have the same logic for invoking the file picker when appropriate, just without the unsnap option because you really just want to tell the user to make the view wider. But again, if you don't otherwise have a reason to support 320px then leave the manifest at 500px and ax all the unsnap code.